# Why do I get '[eclipse.brand] Could not find executable to brand' when building my Eclipse RCP from console?

Tags: ant, gradle, eclipse-rcp

When I export my Eclipse RCP build from a gradle script (which calls ant under the hood), I get the following message in my log:

```
[ant:exec] customAssembly:
[ant:exec] [eclipse.brand] Could not find executable to brand
```

The script finishes, but the executable `eclipse.exe` is missing in the final assembly.

Answer (score 1):

You need the Equinox Executable Plug-In in your target platform: `org.eclipse.equinox.executable`

Here's another good source for common answers to export problems:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseProductDeployment/article.html